# How to generate JSON schema from type constructor using NJsonSchema?

Tags: .net, jsonschema, njsonschema

I'm using `NJsonSchema` for schema generation from `C#` types.

```
public sealed class Config
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public Config([RegularExpression("Name.*123")] string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
}
```

And trying to generate like this:

```
var schema = JsonSchema.FromTypeAsync<Config>().Result;
```

But generator uses class properties instead of constructor for schema generation. How to specify to use constructor?

Comment: Latest version of njs? If yes please create an issue on github

Comment: What do you expect and what is the actual output?